# Return for a push segue

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, segue

I am new to story boards and I am trying to move between table view controllers.

I understand how to set up a segue and how to send data to the new story board but my question is returning data back.  If I use the push style segue it gives me an automatic back button.  I want a page that will create a "job" and save it if they hit save (a bar button I created on the other side of the title) When I set up the segue to go back to the main page from the save button it made that main table view controller a child (instead of simply going back to it's original state).  The work around I was thinking was saving it to a file when they hit save and whenever they load the main table view it loads from that file.  Is this a common and correct way to do this or should I be trying to return that object and save it in the main table view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to use delegation. Since ViewControllers should be as independent as it is possible, we have to minimize dependencies between them. And actually your idea with the file, if I understand it correctly, does it as well. But using files to organize a communication between ViewControllers is not very convinient.
Usually you declare a @protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate for your second ViewController (where you click a "Save" button). With methods like:

```
@protocol YourSecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)yourSecondViewControllerDidCancel:(YourSecondViewController*)controller; //if you have a cancel button
-(void)yourSecondViewControllerDidFinish:(YourSecondViewController*)controller yourDataToReturn:(SomeData*)data andSomeMoreData:(AnotherDataType*)data2;
@end
```

Then you add a property like this to your SecondViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<YourSecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate; //Do not retain it!
```

Then you adopt your protocol in your MainViewController.

```
@interface MainViewController()<YourSecondViewControllerDelegate> //you can do it in the private category to keep the class interface clear.
@end
@implementation
//don't forget to implement those methods here :)
@end
```

And when you trigger your segue from the MainViewController, you can set your MainViewController as a delegate for the SecondViewController:

```
SecondViewController *destinationController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; //Just for example.
destinationController.delegate = self;
//trigger a segue :)
```

When the user presses the Save button in the SecondViewController, you call the delegate's yourSecondViewControllerDidFinish:

```
[self.delegate yourSecondViewControllerDidFinish: self yourDataToReturn: someData andSomeMoreDate: someMoreData];
```

This way MainController's yourSecondViewControllerDidFinish method will be called. And you can pick someData and someMoreData up there.

You can get more details about it in this tutorial:
[Apple's your second iOS app tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a segue to go "back" to a controller, then that segue needs to be an unwind segue. An unwind segue goes back to the same instance of the controller that you came from originally. If you need to send data back to that controller, you can do it in prepareForSegue.

Comment: That makes sense I didn't know about unwind segues.  Is there anything wrong with saving it the child table view controller then reloading it in the main view controller when I get back or is there a better way to save the data?

Comment: @ChewOnThis_Trident, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to save the data just so you can read it in the main controller, or do you need to save it for other reasons?

Comment: I am making an estimating app, and a user can add a job.  Once he does he can take that job and add estimate items to it (material, hourly costs and that sort of thing)  So I want to create the job and save it, then be able to access it from the main page and edit it further (by adding estimate tasks that can be saved to that job).  In a settings page The user can set up the tasks and how much they cost and what unit of measurement they use (time, length, square footage, percentage, that sort of thing).  So I was thinking of having each page be able to save the respective object.